# Can't set fully transparent navigation controller on top of tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I do know how to make transparent controller:

```
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

and it works if in storyboard, in selected ViewController I set `Adjust Scroll View Insets` + `Under Top Bar`, but then part first row loads of screen. If I disable those two options, First row seems to be in place, but then Navigation Controller is all black.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to hide the Navigation bar for the Navigation Controller.

In the view controller that you want to hide from:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]
```

Comment: But I do want to have Navigation Controller, just fully transparent, so that it wouldn't block Table View behind

Comment: Well... You will still HAVE a navigation controller. But it's navigation BAR will be hidden.

Comment: And the buttons will be hidden as well and I need those buttons.
I do have a feeling, that my settings in Storyboard are conflicting and causing this problem

Comment: Correct! My suggestion to you is to not start manipulating the views of a NavigationBar to much. It will give you problems and compatibility issues. I'd suggest adding your own UIButtons to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, I am currently thinking about just simply adding a UIButton

Comment: My experience tells me that you will have much less of a hazzle with that. :) Navigation and toolbars are sacred ground.... Defile it and you will be cursed...